# How to replace commas in a non-numerical list in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

I have a data.frame in R, that is also a list. I want to replace the "," with "." in the numbers. The data.frame is not numerical, but I think it has to be to be able to change the decimal separator.

I tried a lot, but nothing works. I do not want to rearrange or manipulate my data.frame. All I want is to get rid off "," in the deciaml numbers.

```
df <- data.frame(colnames(c("a","b","c")),"row1"=c("2,3","6"),"row2"=c("56,0","56,8"),"row3"=c("1",0"))

#trials to make df numeric and change from , to .

as.numeric(str_replace_all(df,",","."))
as.numeric(unlist(df[ ,2:3]))
lapply(df, as.numeric)
as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",",replacement = ".",df[ ,2:3]))
as.numeric(df$a)
```

What else can I do about this nasty problem?

Comment: Your data is currently not directly reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you read the data incorrectly (you can specify `dec = ","`) while reading the data).

You can use `gsub` to replace commas (`,`) with dot (`.`) and turn them to numeric.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate_all(~ as.numeric(str_replace(., ",", ".")))
```